# Java - Existence value of SQLJ

Tags: java, sqlj

My company using very old java version 1.4.2, and still using .SQLJ, use it in a way like setters and getters, and also data manipulations (add, delete, edit). I know SQLJ is outdated. http://blog.jooq.org/2014/01/03/why-did-sqlj-die/

But for now, I don't actually see what is the actual problem of using SQLJ in my application (my application don't run threads) and this is what i worry about. My question is, is it necessary not to use SQLJ?

Comment: Don't touch the running system, unless you get value out of the change. There's nothing wrong with SQLJ per se. It's just technology that hardly anyone uses...